# writing around the square

Tags: equations, arrows

I hope there was no similar thread (at least I wasn't able to find). I have problem in writing such a thing in latex:

[image]

I would be grateful for any hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use **tikzcd** library for TikZ. Google `commutative diagram in tikz`

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried anything? Can you at least post the code for the bits you need assembled? (It is annoying for people to have to copy from a graphic when writing an answer.)

Comment: I know how to write basic equations, but didn't know how to create such a diagram. Now, I think it can be done also using 3 x 3 matrix.

Comment: What's up with the title?:)'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a commutative diagram, for which the [Xy package](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf) is particularly useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
    X_n\ar[r]^{\text{a.s.}} \ar@{=}[d]^D & X\ar@{=}[d]^D\\
    Y_n                                  & Y
}
\]
\end{document}
```

The package is really versatile for drawing commutative diagrams; check out the documentation for all of the things you can do to decorate objects and arrows.

[image]

Comment: I usually add `cmtip` to the options of `xy`, so the arrow tips are like the standard ones.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X_n \arrow[r,"\text{a.s.}"]
    \arrow[d,shift right=.15em,equal,"D"] &
  X \arrow[d,equal,"D"]\\
Y_n & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The argument to `\arrow` (in brackets) has the direction, possible options like `equal` for getting an “equals sign” instead of an arrow, or `swap` for changing the side of the label (default is the left side looking in the direction of the target); with `shift right` we can move it to the right in order to correct the visual effect induced by the presence of the subscripts; finally, between double quotes, the label.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious about  the little grey horizontal lines at the edges of the double lines? Why they appear?

Comment: @CroCo Good question! It's a bug in the TikZ arrow library, in my opinion.

Comment: @CroCo Note that printers shouldn't print them. The bug can be also blamed to the browsers and their mistakes in anti-aliasing.

Comment: @yo' No, it's a bug nonetheless: the problem is that the object is realized by filling black a rectangle and then drawing a white rectangle to mask of the center part. Try and issue `\pagecolor{blue}` and you'll see.

Comment: @egreg That's clearly explained in the manual. From this point of view, it's a documented feature.

Comment: @yo' I'm appalled anyway. They can and should do better. If you deem the result at the top of page 170 acceptable, I don't.

Answer (score 5):

A demo of what can be done with `pstricks` and with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
%
 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, linewidth=0.5pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=0.6cm, colsep = 1.1cm, shortput=nab}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
%%%nodes
 \smash[b]{X_n} & X \\%
 Y_n & Y
 %%% arrows
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}^{a. s.} 
\psset{arrows=none, doubleline, doublesep=1.4pt}
 \ncline{1,1}{2,1}>{D}
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2}>{D}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
X_n \arrow{r}{a. s.} \arrow[equal]{d}{D} & X \arrow[equal]{d}{D} \\%
Y_n & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A `Tikz` solution

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        node distance =.7cm
    ]%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \node (A)               {$\textbf{X}_{\textbf{n}}$};
     \node (B) [right=of A]  {$\textbf{X}$};
     \node (C) [below=of B]  {$\textbf{Y}$};
     \node (D) [below=of A]  {$\textbf{Y}_{\textbf{n}}$};

    \draw[->,thick] (A) -- node[above] {a.s.} (B);
    \draw[double,thick] (A) -- node[right] {D}(D);
    \draw[double,thick] (B) -- node[right] {D}(C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is only a sketch. Some tuning probably needed. (I am assuming, that it is about probability, not commutative diagrams).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\def\eqD{\stackrel{D}{=}}
\def\roteqD{\rotatebox{-90}{$\eqD$}}

\[
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}
X_n&\;\stackrel{\mathrm{a.s.}}{=}\;&X\\[-7pt]
\roteqD &&\roteqD\\[5pt]
Y_n&&Y
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding a snapshot for the output of the code is always appreciated. Possible upvotes as well.